# Catch Mysql Error in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, error-handling

I have a bash script that queries mysql and I would like to catch the error and echo it .  Here is my code

```
 mysql --silent -h ${sql_server} -P 3306 -u${USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -D${DATABASE} -BNe "$sql_str" | while read -r line
do
    query="$(echo "$line" | cut -f1)"
    database_out="$(echo "$line" | cut -f2)"
    outfile="$(echo "$line" | cut -f3)"
    directory_out="$(echo "$line" | cut -f4)"
    type="$(echo "$line" | cut -f5)"
    host="$(echo "$line" | cut -f6)"
    username="$(echo "$line" | cut -f7)"
    directory_scp="$(echo "$line" | cut -f8)"

    #switch over format types
    case "$type" in 
        csv)
            file_out=$directory_out$outfile"."`date +%Y%m%d`.csv
            mysql -h ${sql_server} -P 3306 -u${USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -D${database_out} -e "$query" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > $file_out
            ;;
        xml)
            file_out=$directory_out$outfile`date +%Y%m%d`.xml
            mysql -h ${sql_server} -P 3306 -u${USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -D${database_out} -e "$query" -X > $file_out
            ;;
        *)
        echo "["$(timestamp)"] : {ERROR} Invalid output format.  Currently only csv and xml output supported."
        ;;
    esac
    str=$file_out" "$username@$host:$directory_scp  
    echo "["$(timestamp)"] : {NOTIFICATION} Attempting to scp "$outfile" to "$username@$host:$directory_scp" - [Started]"
    scp $str
    echo "["$(timestamp)"] : {NOTIFICATION} scp "$outfile" to "$username@$host:$directory_scp" - [Complete]"

done
```

Any ideas.  I would like to catch error and format the error output.

Comment: either catch/parse any output that mysql might spit out, or check its exit code?

Comment: how would I do that.  Can you provide an example.

Comment: `$?` gives you the exit code of the last executed command.

Comment: yeah I attempted that a little bit back now and still can not take error and handle myself.

Comment: [ $? = 0 ] || echo "["$(timestamp)"] : {ERROR} "

Comment: errors are usually dumped to stderr, and you're not capturing that stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 result=$(mysql --silent -h ${sql_server} -P 3306 -u${USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -D${DATABASE} -BNe "$sql_str")
    if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
            echo "["$(timestamp)"] : {ERROR} MySQL error thrown in EOD DUMP"
    else
            while read -r line 

                   ...do something
```

Comment: while running the command i get `timestamp: command not found` and then `[] : {ERROR} MySQL error thrown in EOD DUMP`